# Why would I choose yarn's "resolutions" over an explicit dependency?

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management, yarnpkg

I was reading the [yarn resolutions RFC](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md) and stopped at this:

> The `devDependencies`, `optionalDependencies` and `dependencies` fields always take precedence over the `resolutions` field: if the user defines explicitly a dependency there, it means that he wants that version, even if it's specified with a non-exact specification. So the `resolutions` field only applies to nested-dependencies. Nevertheless, in case of incompatibility between the specification of a non-nested dependency version and a resolution, a warning is issued.

If I can enforce the version of a dependency via the usual dependency fields, why would I choose the (seemingly) more complicated "resolutions" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the version of a dependency via the usual dependency fields for direct package dependencies only, not for dependencies of those dependencies. The `resolutions` field is needed to enforce dependency version throughout all the project for all transitive dependencies.

This section clarifies precedence between usual dependency fields and resolutions for direct dependencies. For the case of direct dependencies usual dependency fields take precedence. It makes sense in the scenario where you have declared resolutions first and then executed `yarn add foo@version`, you want your package to use `foo@version` after that, even if you have stated `resolutions: {foo: 'old_version'}` before.

Comment: Thanks Viktor! Just to make sure I hear you well: by "this section", do you mean your paragraph, the RFC I linked to in my post, or another resource that you forgot to provide a link for?

Comment: Your are welcome! Yeah, I meant the section in the RFC